# Jetpack Compose. selectedContentColor and unselectedContentColor not working in BottomNavigationItem

Tags: navigation, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-navigation-bar

I have code:

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
    val items = listOf(
        BottomNavigationItem.One,
        BottomNavigationItem.Two,
        BottomNavigationItem.Three,
        BottomNavigationItem.Four,
        BottomNavigationItem.Five
    )
    BottomNavigation(
        backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.teal_700),
        contentColor = Color.White
    ) {
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
        items.forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = { Icon(painterResource(id = item.icon), contentDescription = item.title) },
                label = { Text(text = item.title) },
                selectedContentColor = Color.White,
                unselectedContentColor = Color.White.copy(0.4f),
                alwaysShowLabel = true,
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        navController.graph.startDestinationRoute?.let { route ->
                            popUpTo(route) {
                                saveState = true
                            }
                        }
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = true
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

But contentColor and selectedContentColor with unselectedContentColor not working. Selected item didn't change color (and other items didn't have unselectedContentColor)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found bug (or, maybe it's correct situation), but If you have

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
```

properties selectedContentColor and unselectedContentColor won't work. **You must use the following imports:**

```
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.Text
```

Comment: Good catch. For me it was vice-versa. I had M3 NavigationBar with material.Icon and Text.

Comment: I would have never figured out this one ... Thanks a lot!